# If $n>m$, then the spheres $S^n$ and $S^m$ are not homeomorphic?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, differential-topology

We have the following classical result:

> If $n>m$, then the 1-spheres $S^n$ and $S^m$ are not homeomorphic.

Can we prove that with the Jordan-Brouwer theorem? In particular, we set $S^m= (S^m, 0,...,0)\subset S^n$ and note that the set $\mathbb{R^{n+1}}\setminus S^n$ has two connected components but the set $\mathbb{R^{n+1}}\setminus S^m$ has only one connected components. Thus, $S^n$ and $S^m$ cannot be homeomorphic.

Comment: Yes, you can${}$.

Comment: As an alternative proof, if you have proven that $\mathbb R^n$ and $\mathbb R^m$ are not isomorphic if $m\neq n$, then this result is just a corollary, since $S^n$ without a point is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: You can also go backwards (adding instead of removing a point):  if the Euclidean spaces were homeo, so would be their compactifications.

Comment: @Randall Yesss, nice :)

Comment: If you've shown $\dim(S^n)=n$ for all $n$ the result immediately follows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this argument works. Jordan-Brouwer states that any homeomorph of $S^n$
in $\Bbb R^{n+1}$ separates it. There is, as you say, a homeomorph $S^m$
($m<n$) in $\Bbb R^{n+1}$ which does not separate it. So $S^m$ is not
homeomorphic to $S^n$.

Comment: Thanks for answering.